# Operation with two field that exist only in select (SQL - Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

my question is:

```
select shape as "Shape",
       codigo as "GeocodigoTo",
       function(shape) as "X",
       function(shape) as "Y",
      **[X - Y] as "X - Y"**,
...
```

How do I operate the two columns that exist only in Select Statements?

Ps: I don't want do this: function(x) - function(y). That would be slow

Comment: Do you even subquery bro?

Comment: You only have two choices (in Oracle; if I understand that correctly, there are other DB products where you can do what you want). One is to repeat `function(x) - function(y)` - and hope that Oracle is smart enough not to compute `function(x)` and `function(y)` twice. You said you don't want that. The other option is to select `X` and `Y` in a subquery, and then `X-Y` in and outer query.

Comment: "*I don't want do this: function(x) - function(y). That would be slow*" - this depends on the function. If that function is marked `deterministic` then Oracle will only call it once for each row regardless on how many times you write it down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In oracle you can use subquery, in you case:

```
WITH raw_data as
(shape as "Shape",
 codigo as "GeocodigoTo",
 function(shape) as "X",
 function(shape) as "Y" FROM table)
SELECT d.*,X-Y as "X-Y" FROM raw_data;
```

That will avoid invoking function twice.

Comment: That's called a "common table expression", not a sub-query

Comment: That's the term used by the SQL standard.